How-to prevent users from changing the ownership or the permissions on a posix filesystem
My question might look silly because I'm coming from a Windows / NTFS background.
We have a linux filesystem shared across several people. The tree looks like this:
- /data
  |- shared
     |- Alice
     |- Bob

We have set up the permissions on the shared folder with the following permissions drwxrwsr-x and ownership as head_of_department:department.
We noticed that, over time, the permissions got changed. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to find resources on this specific topic on the web.
Is there a way we can lock the permissions to the ones we want?
Or should we have some cron job that resets the permissions periodically?

Do you know who changed them? The head_of_department has the right to change them, is that not desired? Should the root user (administrator) be allowed to change them? Please [edit] your question and clarify exactly what you need and who should be able to do what.

What did the permissions get changed from/to? Are these Alice and Bob's home directories? Is anybody root (UID 0)? Does anybody have sudo?  To change permissions, one needs write access to the (properly mounted) parent directory. Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld, a bash script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.
